# Center menu bar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center my nav bar right now but coming across some difficulty and have no clue how to proceed. I have my nav bar inside a class and a div which is maybe what's confusing me. I have tried to align center and to also float center but no luck.

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
}

div {
  min-height: 75px;
  line-height: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #57df13;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
}

.inner {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header .inner {
  font-size: 125%
}

.menu .inner ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu .inner li {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 18px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.menu .inner li:hover {
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>PandaGamingNetwork</title>
  <link href="CSS/master.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="inner">
      <h1> PandaGamingNetwork </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="inner">
      <ul>
        <li> Home </li>
        <li> About </li>
        <li> Vids </li>
        <li> Memes </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove float:left from .menu .inner li and use display:inline-block;

```
.menu .inner li {
    /* float: left; */
    padding-left: 18px;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Erase everything from you `.inner` rule and add this to center the menu:

```
.inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

And add `padding: 0;` to `.menu .inner ul` to avoid an offset caused by padding.

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
}

div {
  min-height: 75px;
  line-height: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #57df13;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header .inner {
  font-size: 125%
}

.menu .inner ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu .inner li {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 18px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.menu .inner li:hover {
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="inner">
    <h1> PandaGamingNetwork </h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="menu">
  <div class="inner">
    <ul>
      <li> Home </li>
      <li> About </li>
      <li> Vids </li>
      <li> Memes </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```